# Crooked textures on wall

Tags: texturing

I would like to have straight textures on a wall.

[image: Crooked textures]

If have highlighted the parts where my textures look crooked.

I tried removing loop cuts from the wall but that did not solve my problem.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: That is a problem of unwrapping object. Your texture is straight, but UVs are in random positions, you have to ajust the UVs. If dont knou how, look at some tutorial or upload the file I will take a look and post you a solution

Comment: Please link a tutorial where the UVs get adjusted.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPoxqOcUzNQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rng7AYfJk4Q

Hope you will get the idea of how the UVs work from these two. You need to unwrap the wall as a one piece and alight it with the texture.